# Is there a way to send a KeyboardInterrupt to a running Python script in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, keyboard-events, sublimetext3

Running code in Sublime using command-b, and stopping it with ctrl-c results in a cancellation of the build, not a KeyboardInterrupt. Usually, that's okay for my purposes, but when using multiple processes and streams, it results in a lot of zombies.

Is there a way to send an actual KeyboardInterrupt to Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your system sends a SIGINT on ctrl-c (as is usual) you should be able to emulate that by doing:

```
>>> os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

If you want to do it in Python. Or simply type this in the terminal:

```
$ kill -INT pid
```